# grep is not recognized as an internal or external in windows

Tags: windows, python, cmd.exe

I am trying to run this line

```
 scholar.py --txt-globals --author "albert einstein" | grep '\[G\]' | grep Results
```

In the CMD, but I confront this error. I know `grep` is for UNIX but how can I run this line in windows? I have windows 7.

Answer (score 8):

Use `findstr` instead `grep`, because cmd doesn't cover `grep` syntax as it works on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

`CMD` does not have `grep` like unix does. This applies to many commands, such as `sed`, `awk`, `sudo`, `cat`...etc.

However, if you use PowerShell instead of cmd, it has a [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) cmdlet which will allow you to get similar results.

`scholar.py --txt-globals --author "albert einstein" | Select-String '[G]' | Select-String 'Results'`

I haven't tested the Regex. But if `Select-String` isn't giving you the required results you can install [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Comment: I install grep for windows and add its path to environment variable of windows. this error is gone but there is another one.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me

Answer (score 5):

You can install all these nice UNIX commands with Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/).